# Python, Django Unit testing. RequestFactory test doesnt work

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-testing

I have this view that I want to test

```
def change_item(request):
    name_change = request.POST.get('name_change')
    cost_change = request.POST.get('cost_change')
    category_change = request.POST.get('category_change')
    product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
    category_name = Category.objects.get(name = category_change)
    product = Product.objects.get(id__exact = product_id)
    product.name = name_change
    product.category = category_name
    product.price = cost_change
    product.save()
    return HttpResponse()
```

And I wrote a test for It,but it doesn't work (I want to test request)

```
from django.test import RequestFactory
from django.test import TestCase
from views import change_item
from models import Product
from django.utils import unittest


class TestChange_item(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()

    def change_item_test(self):
        # Create an instance of a GET request.
        request = self.factory.get('main/views')
        # Test my_view() as if it were deployed at /customer/details
        response = change_item(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

When I run it I get this in console

```
ERROR: change_item_test (src.main.tests.TestChange_item)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/volodia/work/shopping-helper/src/main/tests.py", line 19, in change_item_test
response = change_item(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 24, in _wrapped_view
if test_func(request.user):
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

What can I do with it ? Or there is some different way of testing requests ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the documentation you will see that you need to [manually add a user to the request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/advanced/). It doesn't do this for you automatically.

```
def change_item_test(self):
    request = self.factory.get('main/views')
    request.user = User.objects.create_user(username="bobalong")
```

Adding a user like this simulates making a logged in request. If this is NOT what you want then you should create an `AnonymousUser` instead. In general the error you were getting should provide you with everything you need to know. It is explicitly telling you that the test is failing because the request doesn't have a `user`. Adding a real user or adding a mock user object to the request is the answer.

Also, you seem to be testing a view that will only work with a POST request. It's going to fail because request.POST does not have the correct dictionary keys. You can create a POST request by doing

```
factory.post('main/views', {'name_change': 'some name'})`
```